# black lines appear on the edges of images in iphone safari

Tags: html, css, ios, mobile-safari, artifacts

I'm at a dead end in solving the problem I'm facing now. I don't know if this is a bug or not, but this problem only appears in the iPhone Safari browser.
here is the screenshot: Iphone 12
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz0Fk.jpg)

you can also see it here:
(https://menoeadengannia.viding.co/)

I've tried adding this to the ornament image css

```
.orn-1 img,
.orn-2 img,
.orn-3 img,
.orn-4 img,
.orn-5 img {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  margin: -2px;
}
```

but it didn't work

Comment: Do the lines come and go if you zoom in and out? Also, please could you put relevant code into your question as the question and any answers will be useless to future readers once that website is mended or is removed. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I am not seeing any lines on a real iPhone SE or on a real iPad. What models/OS versions are you seeing the on? And do the positions of the lines change each time?[But the image I see is different from the images I see on the website].